# Best way to add Django migrations to a django project

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I have a Django application initially created for version 1.6 and I've just finished the upgrade for the last version. All the models has `managed = False` and prior none of them was managed by south and now I want to start using Django migrations for 1.7 version.

Which would be the best and seamless way to do it? I'm afraid that just changing `managed = True` in all models and run `manage.py makemigrations` will make a mess in both migrations files and database.

Thanks

**EDIT**

As was suggested I ran manage.py makemigrations. It created the script `0001_initial` with some model definitions but not for all the objects in models package. It creates 11 tables but I have 19 tables. All models has `managed = True` and I don't have any database router.

Comment: If your database matches your models, then doing what you propose should work fine. What are the problems you're anticipating? (You can at least try `makemigrations` without harm, since all it does is create files, which you can then delete.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most depends by the code

#### The project does not have migrations at all

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

#### The project has South migrations:

you can:

1. move the south migrations in `south_migrations`

   or
2. totally remove the south migrations

and

```
./manage.py makemigrations
./manage.py migrate
```

if you go for option `1` you have to remember to keep uptodate your migrations with both systems (south and django). This is useful only if you want to keep django <1.7 compatibility

#### You have a pluggable application

This is the most complex situataion as you must preserve the south compatibility and you have to manage different version of south. Here the how to:

1. move the south migrations in `south_migrations`
2. run ./manage.py makemigrations
3. to prevent South to load the wrong migratins put the following code into `migration.__init__.py`

```

```
"""
Django migrations

This package does not contain South migrations.  South migrations can be found
in the ``south_migrations`` package.
"""

SOUTH_ERROR_MESSAGE = """\n
For South support, customize the SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES setting like so:

SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'wfp_auth': 'wfp_auth.south_migrations',
}
"""

# Ensure the user is not using Django 1.6 or below with South
try:
    from django.db import migrations  # noqa
except ImportError:
    from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured
raise ImproperlyConfigured(SOUTH_ERROR_MESSAGE)
```

```

Comment: thanks @sax. The project does not have any migrations at all, but it does has a pluggable application (REST Framework), but AFAIK it does not create any model.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the migration from 1.6 to 1.7 on an existing project.  It was fairly painless.

I renamed my old South migrations folders and let the django 1.7 migrations create a new one. (i.e. $mv appname/migrations appname/migrations.south)  That will make it easier to go back to South for any reason and will keep from having a jumbled mess of both in your migrations folders.